# jquery get select() selection

Tags: jquery, select, textarea

think this should be an easy one... I want to get the currently selected text using jquery's select() function.

```
$('textarea').select(function(selection) {
    alert(selection);
});
```

This returns [object Object]... how do I return the selected text?

Many thanks

Comment: selected text on the p age or select box's selected option text?

Comment: i want to return the selected text within the textarea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From jquery's select() doc:

> The method for retrieving the current
>   selected text differs from one browser
>   to another. A number of jQuery
>   plug-ins offer cross-platform
>   solutions.

a quick google search for "jquery get selected text" turned up this:

http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html
this:
http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html
and many more

Comment: Your Google searching powers are clearing beyond mine :) thanks Andy, very handy.